# How to give position zero of spinner a prompt value?

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-spinner

The database is then transferring the data to a spinner which I want to leave position 0 blank so I can add a item to the spinner with no value making it look like a prompt.  I have been going at it all day.  FAil after Fail

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Button AddBtn;
EditText et;
EditText cal;
Spinner spn;
SQLController SQLcon;
ProgressDialog PD;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    AddBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addbtn_id);
    et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_id);
    cal = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_cal);
    spn = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_id);

    spn.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListenerWrapper(
            new OnItemSelectedListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent,
                        View view, int pos, long id) {

                    SQLcon.open();

                    Cursor c = SQLcon.readData();
                    if (c.moveToPosition(pos)) {

                        String name = c.getString(c
                                .getColumnIndex(DBhelper.MEMBER_NAME));
                        String calories = c.getString(c
                                .getColumnIndex(DBhelper.KEY_CALORIES));
                        et.setText(name);
                        cal.setText(calories);

                    }

                    SQLcon.close();
                    // closing database

                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

            }));
    SQLcon = new SQLController(this);
    // opening database

    SQLcon.open();

    loadtospinner();

    AddBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            new MyAsync().execute();

        }
    });
}

public void loadtospinner() {

    ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();

    Cursor c = SQLcon.readData();
    c.moveToFirst();
    while (!c.isAfterLast()) {

        String name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DBhelper.MEMBER_NAME));
        String calories = c.getString(c
                .getColumnIndex(DBhelper.KEY_CALORIES));

        al.add(name + ", Calories: " + calories);

        c.moveToNext();
    }

    ArrayAdapter<String> aa1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
            al);

    spn.setAdapter(aa1);

    // closing database
    SQLcon.close();

}

private class MyAsync extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

        super.onPreExecute();
        PD = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        PD.setTitle("Please Wait..");
        PD.setMessage("Loading...");
        PD.setCancelable(false);
        PD.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        String name = et.getText().toString();
        String calories = cal.getText().toString();
        // opening database
        SQLcon.open();
        // insert data into table

        SQLcon.insertData(name, calories);

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        loadtospinner();
        PD.dismiss();

    }
}
}
```

**DataBase**

```
public class SQLController {
private DBhelper dbhelper;
private Context ourcontext;
private SQLiteDatabase database;

public SQLController(Context c) {
    ourcontext = c;
}

public SQLController open() throws SQLException {
    dbhelper = new DBhelper(ourcontext);
    database = dbhelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;

}

public void close() {
    dbhelper.close();
}

public void insertData(String name, String calories) {
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(DBhelper.MEMBER_NAME, name);

    cv.put(DBhelper.KEY_CALORIES, calories);
    database.insert(DBhelper.TABLE_MEMBER, null, cv);
}

public Cursor readData() {
    String[] allColumns = new String[] { DBhelper.MEMBER_ID,
            DBhelper.MEMBER_NAME, DBhelper.KEY_CALORIES };
    Cursor c = database.query(DBhelper.TABLE_MEMBER, allColumns, null,
            null, null, null, null);
    if (c != null) {
        c.moveToFirst();
    }
    return c;
}
}
```

**Helper**

```
public class DBhelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

// TABLE INFORMATTION
public static final String TABLE_MEMBER = "member";
public static final String MEMBER_ID = "_id";
public static final String MEMBER_NAME = "name";
public static final String KEY_CALORIES = "calories";

// DATABASE INFORMATION
static final String DB_NAME = "MEMBER.DB";
static final int DB_VERSION = 2;

// TABLE CREATION STATEMENT
private static final String CREATE_TABLE = "create table " + TABLE_MEMBER
        + "(" + MEMBER_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
        + MEMBER_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL," + KEY_CALORIES
        + " INT NOT NULL);";

public DBhelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_MEMBER);
    onCreate(db);
}
}
```

Comment: The point is, you want to store from 2nd row of table in database?

Comment: I would like to have the first position of the database to be null and the one after that to be the first item users can add items to.  If that is what you are asking.

Comment: See my answer below and let me know if it works or ask where you get confused.

Comment: I guess you're storing the results retrieved from db in a list and then you're passing that list to the adapter. So when you get the populated list try doing `list.add(0,"")`, before passing it to the adapter.

Comment: @Aniruddha   List<String> spinnerArray = new ArrayList<String>();   
  spinnerArray.add(0, "YOU MESSAGE");  ?

Comment: @Aniruddha No it was a database issue thanks you though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following:

```
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.yourSpinner);
ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, spinnerArray); 
spinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);
```

**Update:**

Your **spinnerArray** should have values from database with **first value as prompt**

**For example:**

```
List<String> spinnerArray = new ArrayList<String>();
spinnerArray.add("YOU MESSAGE");
```

And then you can use **for loop** to add values to **spinnerArray** as follow:

```
for(//loop until you need values to be added)
```

Add values to spinnerArray as:

```
spinnerArray.add(value1);
spinnerArray.add(value1);
spinnerArray.add(value1);
//so on.
```

and finally pass it as last argument while creating **spinnerArrayAdapter** as above. And this should solve your problem.

**Update1:**

If you don't want to get item at position 0 you can do the following:

```
if(spinner.getSelectedItem().equals("YOUR MESSAGE"){//may be you want to ignorecase using equalsIgnoreCase() method
//display message that you haven't selected anything
}else{
//do anything you want
}
```

**Populate dummy data:**

Change your **onCreate()** in DBhelper class to:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);

    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(DBhelper.MEMBER_NAME, "DUMMY NAME");

        cv.put(DBhelper.KEY_CALORIES, "DUMMY CALORIES");
        database.insert(DBhelper.TABLE_MEMBER, null, cv);
}
```

Comment: I tried what you said and it still has the same problem.  The first item in the spinner says the correct message but it takes the value of the item below it on the list.  I am testing it with a click of the spinner item to string the data back to the editTexts.

Comment: Thats why I want the data to be entered at position 1 rather than position 0.  That would solve my issue.  I just dont know how to get the data to skip position 0.

Comment: Is the first item displaying value as you have passed? In my answer "YOUR MESSAGE"?

Comment: did you try using, "getSelectedItem()" method?

Comment: It is Displaying "YOUR MESSAGE" but when YOUR MESSAGE is clicked it string the values of the first item in the database added by the user.

Comment: I am using setOnItemSelectedListener

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: The first item in the spinner displays "YOUR MESSAGE."  When I add items to the database it still displays "YOUR MESSAGE," but when I click the "YOUR MESSAGE" in the spinner it is strings the first values of the database.  The spinner is thinking the first item "YOUR MESSAGE" is the first item in the database.  It adds the items to the spinner when entered but takes no value due to position of the first item "YOUR MESSAGE" in the spinner.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59780/discussion-between-eugene-h-and-nabin).

Comment: @EugeneH check my answer. It will help you.

Answer (score 2):

You're getting the data from db in `al` ArrayList. Then you can do the following

```
al.add(0, "YOUR MESSAGE");
```

It adds YOUR MESSAGE string at `0th` index.

```
Inserts the specified element at the specified position in this list. Shifts the element currently at that position (if any) and any subsequent elements to the right (adds one to their indices).
```

After this pass the list to arrayadapter

```
ArrayAdapter<String> aa1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
            al);

    spn.setAdapter(aa1);
```

Please do check [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add%28int,%20E%29)

**EDIT**

Here is the code

```
public void loadtospinner() {

    ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();

    Cursor c = SQLcon.readData();
    c.moveToFirst();
    while (!c.isAfterLast()) {

        String name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DBhelper.MEMBER_NAME));
        String calories = c.getString(c
                .getColumnIndex(DBhelper.KEY_CALORIES));

        al.add(name + ", Calories: " + calories);

        c.moveToNext();
    }

    al.add(0, "YOUR MESSAGE");    // do this after while loop and that's it. 


    ArrayAdapter<String> aa1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
            al);

    spn.setAdapter(aa1);

    // closing database
    SQLcon.close();

}
```

Comment: It's kind of helpful but he had something else. Voted you though :-)